# Not proper alignment for nodes in a `TikZ` diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code renders a diagram of a number line.  I have `-8`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `10` labeled on it.  The distance between any two consecutive numbers is `3`.  (I magnified the figure by `3/4`.)  The labels that are typeset from the node commands for `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `10` are aligned perfectly along a horizontal line under them.  Why is `-8` not aligned on this same horizontal line?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (-8) at ({(3/4)*(-4)},0);
\coordinate (a) at ({(3/4)*-2.5},0);
\coordinate (b) at ({(3/4)*(-1)},0);
\coordinate (c) at ({(3/4)*0.5},0);
\coordinate (d) at ({(3/4)*2},0);
\coordinate (e) at ({(3/4)*3.5},0);
\coordinate (10) at ({(3/4)*5},0);

%The labels for -8 and 10 are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] (label_for_-8) at ($(-8) +(0,-0.15)$){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}8};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0]  (label_for_10) at ($(10) +(0,-0.15)$){10};

%The labels for a, b, c, d, and e are typeset.
\path[name path=a_path_for_the_label_a_b_c_d_e] (label_for_-8.south) -- (label_for_10.south);
\path[name path=path_for_the_label_a] (a) -- ($(a) +(0,-0.5)$);
\path[name intersections={of=path_for_the_label_a and a_path_for_the_label_a_b_c_d_e, by=label_for_a}];
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at (label_for_a){\textit{a}};
\path[name path=path_for_the_label_b] (b) -- ($(b) +(0,-0.5)$);
\path[name intersections={of=path_for_the_label_b and a_path_for_the_label_a_b_c_d_e, by=label_for_b}];
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at (label_for_b){\textit{b}};
\path[name path=path_for_the_label_c] (c) -- ($(c) +(0,-0.5)$);
\path[name intersections={of=path_for_the_label_c and a_path_for_the_label_a_b_c_d_e, by=label_for_c}];
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at (label_for_c){\textit{c}};
\path[name path=path_for_the_label_d] (d) -- ($(d) +(0,-0.5)$);
\path[name intersections={of=path_for_the_label_d and a_path_for_the_label_a_b_c_d_e, by=label_for_d}];
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at (label_for_d){\textit{d}};
\path[name path=path_for_the_label_e] (e) -- ($(e) +(0,-0.5)$);
\path[name intersections={of=path_for_the_label_e and a_path_for_the_label_a_b_c_d_e, by=label_for_e}];
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at (label_for_e){\textit{e}};


%The number line is drawn.
\draw[latex-latex] ({(3/4)*(-5)},0) -- ({(3/4)*6},0);


%Tick marks are drawn.
\draw ($(-8) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(-8) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(a) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(a) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(b) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(b) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(c) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(c) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(d) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(d) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(e) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(e) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(10) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(10) +(0,-2pt)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If in behind of your MWE is only some exercise and not anything else than your MWE can be rewritten in the following much simpler form:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.42,
every node/.append style = {text height=1em, text depth=0.5ex, inner sep=0pt},
                        ]
% x-axis 
\draw[latex-latex] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0);
\foreach \x [count=\xx from -3] in {-8, a, b, c, d, e, 10}
{
\ifnum\xx=-3
    \draw (\xx,1mm) -- + (0,-2mm) node[below,xshift=-1ex] {$\x$};
\else
    \draw (\xx,1mm) -- + (0,-2mm) node[below] {$\x$};
\fi
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Above code should be self-explanatory ...

[image]

Comment: Your code renders a nice display.   I posted this code, though, was to get an explanation for `-8` not being aligned with the other nodes.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire, it seems that my MWE is not so self-explanatory as I imagine. With option `text height=1em` all nodes have the same height, consequently they align properly (so far if you not have in text letter g, j, p, q, y. If they are also used, than you need also to define the text depth too. For example `text depth=0.5ex` (added to answer). Otherwise, it is not clear to me, why you wrote so complicated code :)

Comment: I suppose that the `\text height` for nodes `-8` and `10` are the same.  If this is the case, these two nodes should be the same distance below the number line.  They are not.  This could have been the question in my post.  Why aren't `-8` and `10` typeset equidistant from the number line?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire, as far as I can see, they have in my MWE equal distance. If you disagree, than is the best to ask new question about this with simple MWE as `\documentclass[tikz, margin=3cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1,0) -- (11,0);
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,10}
  \node[draw=red, very thin, text height=1em, text depth=0.5ex, inner sep=0pt,below] at (\i,0) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`. Maybe some font guru will give better insight than I'm able to do.

Comment: Include the command `\draw[green,  name path=a_path_for_the_label_a_b_c_d_e] (label_for_-8.south) -- (label_for_10.south);` at the end of the `tikzpicture` environment.  You will see the alignment that I want.

Comment: please edit your question. on this way more people will see, what you want. even better, consider my previous comment and ask new question.

Comment: See `Not proper alignment for nodes in a `TikZ` diagram (Version 2)`.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire, do you observe this discrepancy in my solution? I don't, so I don't understand you, what you like to tell me. *Note*: my MWE is very different from yours ...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some reason for making things complicated that does not show in your example, what's wrong with something as simple as this?  I don't believe you need intersections and all the paths that you have used:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (-8) at ({(3/4)*(-4)},0);
\coordinate (a)  at ({(3/4)*-2.5},0);
\coordinate (b)  at ({(3/4)*(-1)},0);
\coordinate (c)  at ({(3/4)*0.5},0);
\coordinate (d)  at ({(3/4)*2},0);
\coordinate (e)  at ({(3/4)*3.5},0);
\coordinate (10) at ({(3/4)*5},0);

% The labels are typeset.
\node[anchor=base] at ($(-8) +(0,-12pt)$){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}8};
\node[anchor=base] at ($(a)  +(0,-12pt)$){\textit{a}};
\node[anchor=base] at ($(b)  +(0,-12pt)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=base] at ($(c)  +(0,-12pt)$){\textit{c}};
\node[anchor=base] at ($(d)  +(0,-12pt)$){\textit{d}};
\node[anchor=base] at ($(e)  +(0,-12pt)$){\textit{e}};
\node[anchor=base] at ($(10) +(0,-12pt)$){10};

% The number line is drawn.
\draw[latex-latex] ({(3/4)*(-5)},0) -- ({(3/4)*6},0);

% Tick marks are drawn.
\draw ($(-8) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(-8) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(a)  +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(a)  +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(b)  +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(b)  +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(c)  +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(c)  +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(d)  +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(d)  +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(e)  +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(e)  +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(10) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(10) +(0,-2pt)$);

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

It produces this, which is perfectly aligned (notice the `anchor=base`):
[image: result]

What's more, it will stay aligned even if you have, say, a `g` label, i.e., a character which extends below the baseline.

Comment: To be consistent with other code in a file, I would like to modify the code in my post to get `-8` aligned at the `south` on the same horizontal line as `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `10`.  Why isn't it aligned?!

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire, the others are not aligned either.  They just look to be aligned.  You need something like the `anchor=base` option to align them.

Comment: I magnified the display by 12 - they are aligned at the `south`.

Comment: Include the command `\draw[green,  name path=a_path_for_the_label_a_b_c_d_e] (label_for_-8.south) -- (label_for_10.south);` at the end of the `tikzpicture` environment.  You will see the alignment that I want.